# How to stop a heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I have a staging server hosted on heroku, I just want to bring it down, but not destroy the app. How can I do it? Do I have any command like 'heroku stop' like 'heroku restart' for restarting?

OR

Is there a way to automate the server to turn off itself when it exceeds the 750 hr free usage?

Actually I don't want the server so I am trying to stop it, or leave it for the free hours.

Comment: 24*31=744, so as long as you have 1 web dyno it'll always be free. No need to stop it.

Comment: I have rake tasks, scheduler mailers, crons etc, so It exceeds 750.. Also few rake tasks are running like 5 hours or so which is supposed to be ended in 10 mins..

Comment: The pricing page implies you can set the number of web dynos to 0.

Comment: You can always put something irrelevant in the Procfile so it doesn't launch your rails app/workers/crons, etc.. or enable the maintenance mode

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811453/how-to-stop-an-app-on-heroku

Comment: You can also restart it - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14612695/631619

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to the account, and click on the resource and then bring down the dyno count to 0 and the save. Now you can check by trying to open the site. It will be down.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton how do you stop Cedar then?

Answer (score 7):

You can scale individual non-web processes down to zero quite happily:

```
$ heroku ps:scale worker=0
$ heroku ps:scale resque=0
etc...
```

and web to 1:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

As Mischa says, you get one free dyno running, so leave your 1 web dyno running (I'm not sure you can stop the last web process)

Comment: in fact you can. With heroku's new procfile, apps aren't limited to web processes and are allowed to remove them altogether if they're not needed.

Comment: Indeed - but that requires a redeploy in order to stop.

Answer (score 4):

You can put it under maintenance, which stops it but doesn't delete it:

```
heroku maintenance:on
```

More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode

Comment: Not sure if this exactly helps. From their page `"Enabling or disabling maintenance mode generally doesn’t alter running dynos. Web dynos continue to run as before"`

Answer (score 2):

Easily disable/enable the App by going to your `Heroku dashboard` ==> `resource tab` the rest is on the picture below:

[image]