# Using Heroku with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github

I have two questions about general usage with Heroku and RoR:

1) after I deploy my application onto Heroku, how can I apply new changes that I make?

2) After I deploy my application to Heroku, how do I "turn off" the server so that I can run my app locally again via localhost:3000? (for development & testing purposes)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using git to manage your project, you apply changes to Heroku by pushing them. This might look something like this:

```
git push heroku master
```

This pushes the master branch of your git project to Heroku.

To "turn off" your app on Heroku, you can do two things:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=0
```

This completely turns off the application. You can also put it in maintenance mode, which simply prevents traffic to it:

```
$ heroku maintenance:on
```

That said, you don't need to turn off your app on Heroku while developing locally. The two environments are completely independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this link helps for part 1. Should be able to commit and push your changes using git push heroku master.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#tracking-your-app-in-git

For part 2: will scaling your dynos back to 0 work for your case?

[How to stop an app on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811453/how-to-stop-an-app-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1):

1. When you make a change, just push the git repository to heroku again with`git push heroku master`.
   The server will automatically restart with the changed system.
2. You seem to have a misconception.  You can always run your local development server regardless of what Heroku is doing (unless some other service your app connects to would become confused, of course; but if that happens, there is probably something wrong with your design).  Nonetheless, if you want to stop the application on Heroku, just scale it to zero web dynos:  `heroku ps:scale web=0`.